# Command Line Returning Blank

Tags: java, arrays, input, java.util.scanner

After entering file to be processed the command line jumps to next line but remains blank, as opposed to printing the desired array.  I want to call the getInputScanner() method to produce the scanner that accesses the file, after the file is entered by the user the command line jumps to the next line, as opposed to processing any of the text.  Any ideas why?

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.io.*;


public class Test {
   public static void main(String [] args) { 

      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

      Scanner input = getInputScanner(console);

      System.out.println("{" + nameArr(input) + "}");

   }

   public static Scanner getInputScanner(Scanner console) {

      System.out.print("Please enter a file to process: ");
      File file = new File(console.next());
      while (!file.exists()) {
         System.out.print("\nFile does not exists.\nPlease enter a new file name: ");
         file = new File(console.next());
      }
      try {
         Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
         return fileScanner;
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("File not found");
        }
      return null;
    }

   public static String [] nameArr(Scanner input) {

      int count = 0;
      while (input.hasNextLine()) {
         count++;
      }

      String [] nameArray = new String[count];

      while (input.hasNextLine()) {

         String line = input.nextLine();

         for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
            nameArray[i] = lineProcess(input.nextLine());
         }
      }
      return nameArray;
   }

   public static String lineProcess(String line) {
      Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);

      String line2 = lineScan.nextLine();

      String lineString[] = line2.split(" ");

      String name = lineString[0];

      return name;

   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've and infinite `loop` since you're not advancing the scanner calling `input.nextLine()`:

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
   count++;
}
```

I see other parts of the code which I'm thing that are wrong, try using `java.util.List` instead of `array` to collect the `names` in the lines of your processed file:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String [] args) { 

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        Scanner input = getInputScanner(console);

        List<String> nameList = nameArr(input);
        for(String name : nameList){
            System.out.println("{ "+ name  + " } ");
        }

    }

    public static Scanner getInputScanner(Scanner console) {

        System.out.print("Please enter a file to process: ");
        File file = new File(console.next());
        while (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.print("\nFile does not exists.\nPlease enter a new file name: ");
            file = new File(console.next());
        }
        try {
            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
            return fileScanner;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static List<String> nameArr(Scanner input) {

        List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            nameList.add(lineProcess(input.nextLine()));
        }
        return nameList;
    }

    public static String lineProcess(String line) {

        return line.split(" ")[0];

    }
}
```

Comment: How so? Wouldn't input.hasNextLine() count the entire file that is being entered in getInputScanner() and count would then equal the number of lines in the file?

Comment: If you don't advance scanner calling `nextLine()`, the `hasNextLine()` method always return `true`.

Comment: @LeSexyNinja I edit my answer to suggest a possibly alternative way to do it.

Comment: `arrays` are constant in length, better use `java.util.List`, anywise if you want to use and `array` instead: you've to scan the file twice, the first to count the lines and the second to parse it line by line and putting the results in the `array` positions.

Comment: ok, i cannot find an answer for arrays and how to scan it twice. How do i scan it twice?

Comment: @LeSexyNinja, I told you that there is a wrong `loop` in your code also I give you a alternative way to do so and also I don't recommend to use arrays however I suggest you a way to with it... if it's not enough for you, write the solution yourself.